# TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable?

Tags: python, discord, roblox

Ive look at a lot of forums about this , but it just doesnt make sense , im starting to code in python and all these big words are just not making sense to me , so if anyone could help me , i would be very grateful , so anyways on to the problem

```
import requests, os
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook, DiscordEmbed


cookie = input('type ya roblo cookie :')
ccheck = requests.get("https://www.roblox.com/mobileapi/userinfo", cookies={".ROBLOSECURITY": cookie}).json()
username = str(ccheck["UserName"])

webhook = DiscordWebhook(url='https://discord.com/api/webhooks/998375746894581842/eXrz9ow5FrPMfWY76D6xIqoQI-410H4UsLUzGjRITcNHW0NEjTfPD-JBgjy88FoSxMgA', content={username})
response = webhook.execute()
```

So im trying get info from an api from roblox , just like very simple , but i have no idea
what im doing wrong to bring `TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable`
This is working on all my other programs up to a few days ago i feel like , idk if its a me problem or roblox problem , or a discord_webhook problem , thanks for anything !
Full error log here
https://hastebin.com/isawoyepon.sql

Comment: `content={username}` makes the content a `set` objet, but `set` objects are not JSON serializable. Why are you making content a `set` with a single element? That doesn't make any sense

Comment: what is the actual api call you want to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your error, I think that the problem is in this line:

`"C:\Users\jonat\Documents\WIP Programs\Discord\ViperDT\help\robloxocookie.py", line 10`

If we check the library code we can find, that the DiscordWebhook can take an argument content wich can be only [string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str), [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binary-sequence-types-bytes-bytearray-memoryview), or [None](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html?highlight=none#None) (this is an optional argument). 
`content: Optional[Union[str, bytes]]` [docs](https://github.com/lovvskillz/python-discord-webhook/blob/c5af6ae2eae76b720be3741cd2602243a0919248/discord_webhook/webhook.py#L225)

In your code you pass the [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) `content={username}` with one element, string value for username

You should try to change your code by removing the brackets outside the username in the content assignment. For example:

```
webhook = DiscordWebhook(
url='https://discord.com/api/webhooks/998375746894581842/eXrz9ow5FrPMfWY76D6xIqoQI-410H4UsLUzGjRITcNHW0NEjTfPD-JBgjy88FoSxMgA',
content=username
)
```

Comment: Thanks , must of just over looked it , really helpful !